# Kendo UI multiselect flashing after removing item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I am using a kendo multi-select of version(2015.1.521). It is located in the lower side of the page. Widow size is increasing after selecting items. After removing some item from option using x icon, multi-select does not open. Is there any solution?

[dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EWIrOVoX)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't open' ?

Comment: It starts flashing, I mean it opens and get closed quickly. You can see in the dojo.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this multiple times but it seems to be working fine at my end. No sudden flash or closing of window noticed. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Use chrome in incognito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a workaround where I am checking for active element.
[Solution dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oqOyEnUb/2)

```
 $("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose:false,
    close: function (e) {
        var activeElement = document.activeElement.getAttribute('aria-owns');
        var currentId = this.tagList[0].id;
        if (activeElement != undefined && activeElement != null && activeElement.includes(currentId)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem. On the other hand, I wasn't able to reproduce it with a current version. That tells me, that it must have been a bug which has been fixed in the meantime.

The only way I found out which fixes the problem for me at 2015.1.521 is to refresh the Widget, once the problem occurred.

```
$("#required").data("kendoMultiSelect").refresh();
```

Now the question is, how do you know (programmatically) that you are in that error-state? Maybe you could refresh it on a regular basis. Until you upgrade to a newer version, it's going to be a workaround.

Comment: I can not go with version upgrade. I tried your suggestion calling refresh() on multiselect close() but its still the same

Comment: $("#required").kendoMultiSelect({
        autoClose:false,
        close: function (e) {
            this.refresh();
        }
      });

Comment: I just can confirm manual solution: 1) open your Dojo in Full Screen Mode 2) Follow steps to get it damaged 3) Open Developer Console 4) execute the Refresh function 5) MultiSelect "repaired" (until damaged again with a few clicks). I can't help with the right wiring in events, sorry. It's always a sad situation when fighting old Bugs which you know have been fixed already. The Bug is (_was_) in the Kendo source. You won't be able to do much about it.